# How do I display a single character randomly on assembly?

Tags: assembly, random

I'm writing an assembly code which should display a character randomly. In this code, I use the function generateRandom to get random values (using CX:DX) which I copy to row and column. As you can see, I use the same function for row and column. However, no character is displayed. I tried changing the values and variables and found that the character isn't displayed whenever a variable is assigned to dh. The variable row and column work fine when assigned to dl. The character is only displayed whenever I assign a numeric value directly to dh. It seems that the problem lies with the dh register but I'm not sure what exactly is wrong with it.

```
.model small
.data
    row db 3
    column db 3
    random db '@'
   ;delaytime db 18
.stack 100h
.code

display proc
    mov dh, row
    mov dl, column
    xor bh, bh
    mov ah, 02h
    int 10h
    mov al, random
    xor bh, bh
    mov cx, 1
    mov ah, 0Ah
    int 10h
    mov dh, 0
    ret
display endp

generateRandom proc
    mov ah, 00h
    int 1Ah      
    mov  ax, dx
    xor  dx, dx
    mov  cx, 10    
    div  cx      
    add dl, 48
    ret
generateRandom endp

main    proc

    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    ;start

    ;video mode
    mov al, 03h
    mov ah, 00h
    int 10h

    call generateRandom
    mov row, dl
    call generateRandom
    mov column, dl
    call display

    ;end
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h

main endp
end main
```

Comment: generateRandom is only suitable to generate random *ASCII* digits.  Your display doesn't have 58 rows.

Comment: I tried changing 48 to 10 for row and it worked! Thanks for making that one clear. I'll adjust the value for column as well. The display should have 25 rows but when I try to make the value 25 or even 20, the character still isn't displayed from time to time. What exact value should I use to make sure it's in the screen?

Comment: Pass a modulus to your 'generateRandom' function instead of hard-coding it in there, and add a suitable base value (30h for printable charactor, 0 for row/column) at the point of use. The modulus for the random digit would be 10, for row and column it would be # of rows/columns (or 25 and 80, if you want to hard-code things).